Uninitialized prometheus metric with increase method
I want to use sum(increase(my_metric{}[5m])) but with the first entry i get 0 because it does not read it as an increase when there is no previous value with this metric. In my case cannot initialize it in application code since it has dynamic tag.
Is there a way to initialize it somehow in Grafana or to do it in different way?

You can try something like increase((my_metric*1 or (my_metric offset -5m)*0) [5m:]), but this trick is own can of worms.

That worked, but I am getting unexpected peaks. As you said, this trick is own can of worms.
